# How to make my draggable object always on top and can move freely?

Tags: unity

why my object is behind another object and also disappear when dragging around like this

[image]

as you can see the item or draggable object is always behind the second one, also behind all panel like this [image]

this is my draggabe script :

```
public event Action<PointerEventData> OnBeginDragHandler;
public event Action<PointerEventData> OnDragHandler;
public event Action<PointerEventData, bool> OnEndDragHandler;
public bool FollowCursor { get; set; } = true;
public Vector3 StartPosition;
public bool CanDrag { get; set; } = true;

private Color backgroundColor;
[SerializeField] private Image backgroundImage;

public RectTransform rectTransform;
public Canvas canvas;

private void Start()
{
    rectTransform = GetComponent<RectTransform>();
    canvas = FindObjectOfType<Canvas>();
    backgroundImage = GetComponentInChildren<Image>();

    backgroundColor = backgroundImage.color;
}

public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    backgroundColor.a = .4f;
    backgroundImage.color = backgroundColor;

    if (!CanDrag)
    {
        return;
    }

    OnBeginDragHandler?.Invoke(eventData);
}

public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    backgroundColor.a = 1f;

    if (!CanDrag)
    {
        return;
    }

    OnDragHandler?.Invoke(eventData);

    if (FollowCursor)
    {
        rectTransform.anchoredPosition += eventData.delta / canvas.scaleFactor;
    }
}

public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    backgroundColor.a = 1f;
    backgroundImage.color = backgroundColor;

    if (!CanDrag)
    {
        return;
    }

    var results = new List<RaycastResult>();
    EventSystem.current.RaycastAll(eventData, results);

    _DropArea dropArea = null;

    foreach (var result in results)
    {
        dropArea = result.gameObject.GetComponent<_DropArea>();

        if (dropArea != null)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    if (dropArea != null)
    {
        if (dropArea.Accept(this))
        {
            dropArea.Drop(this);
            OnEndDragHandler?.Invoke(eventData, true);
            return;
        }
    }

    rectTransform.anchoredPosition = StartPosition;
    OnEndDragHandler?.Invoke(eventData, false);
}

public void OnInitializePotentialDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    StartPosition = rectTransform.anchoredPosition;
}
```

### What I've tried

- I already using this `rectTransform.SetAsFirstSibling();` like Digiti said
- also using `gameobject.transform.SetParent(rectTransform)` onBeginDrag and using `gameobject.transform.SetParent(blankRectrasform)` onEndDrag but the draggable it cant move am I doing wrong

this script after adding those :

```
 public event Action<PointerEventData> OnBeginDragHandler;
public event Action<PointerEventData> OnDragHandler;
public event Action<PointerEventData, bool> OnEndDragHandler;
public bool FollowCursor { get; set; } = true;
public Vector3 StartPosition;
public bool CanDrag { get; set; } = true;

private Color backgroundColor;
[SerializeField] private Image backgroundImage;

public RectTransform rectTransform;
public RectTransform blankRectrasform;
public Canvas canvas;

private void Start()
{
    rectTransform = transform.parent.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
    blankRectrasform = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("fp").GetComponent<RectTransform>();
    canvas = FindObjectOfType<Canvas>();
    backgroundImage = GetComponentInChildren<Image>();

    backgroundColor = backgroundImage.color;
}

public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    backgroundColor.a = .4f;
    backgroundImage.color = backgroundColor;

    if (!CanDrag)
    {
        return;
    }

    OnBeginDragHandler?.Invoke(eventData);

    gameObject.transform.SetParent(blankRectrasform);

    rectTransform.SetAsLastSibling();//Becomes last in parent
}

public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    backgroundColor.a = 1f;

    if (!CanDrag)
    {
        return;
    }

    OnDragHandler?.Invoke(eventData);

    if (FollowCursor)
    {
        rectTransform.anchoredPosition += eventData.delta / canvas.scaleFactor;
    }
}

public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    backgroundColor.a = 1f;
    backgroundImage.color = backgroundColor;
    if (!CanDrag)
    {
        return;
    }

    gameObject.transform.SetParent(rectTransform);

    var results = new List<RaycastResult>();
    EventSystem.current.RaycastAll(eventData, results);

    _DropArea dropArea = null;

    foreach (var result in results)
    {
        dropArea = result.gameObject.GetComponent<_DropArea>();

        if (dropArea != null)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    if (dropArea != null)
    {
        if (dropArea.Accept(this))
        {
            dropArea.Drop(this);
            OnEndDragHandler?.Invoke(eventData, true);
            return;
        }
    }

    rectTransform.anchoredPosition = StartPosition;
    OnEndDragHandler?.Invoke(eventData, false);
}

public void OnInitializePotentialDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    StartPosition = rectTransform.anchoredPosition;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

UI RectTransfroms display in a top(behind) to bottom(front) order.
Try to set up your draggable items panel in front of all others (last in hierarchy), and use rectTransform.SetAsLastSibling(); in OnBeginDrag();

```
public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
{
  backgroundColor.a = .4f;
  backgroundImage.color = backgroundColor;

if (!CanDrag)
{
    return;
}

rectTransform.SetAsLastSibling();//Becomes last in parent

OnBeginDragHandler?.Invoke(eventData); 
}
```

For further in-frontness, use an empty RectTransform panel as the last in your panels in heirarchy. Reference it in code, and parent the object to it while OnDrag() using transform.SetParent(frontPanel), and reset it to original parent OnEndDrag() using transform.SetParent(originalPanel);

Comment: inside content or I just make a random on canvas and setParent there?

Comment: Actually, I already use rectTransform.SetAsLastSibling(), and for transform setparent that actually works when `transform` to `frontpanel` after on `dragEnd` i set back to the original but the position is not original. am i missing something ?

Comment: 1. put frontPanel inside viewport, below content. this causes it to render above everything in content.

Comment: 2.In your post update `OnEndDrag()` you are setting 
    `gameObject.transform.SetParent(rectTransform);`
which is parenting it to itself. Instead use 
_`gameObject.transform.SetParent(originalPanel);`_
where originalPanel has been set in OnBeginDrag() as the parent; `OnBeginDrag{... originalPanel=transform.parent;...}`. 
Edit `You may only want to reset position if `dropArea == null` meaning there is no where to drop, otherwise the dropArea panel will accept the draggable and give it new position